# If the x and y values for the fill function are vectors, what do the numbers represent?

Tags: matlab, math

I working on a Matlab worksheet to study for my final. I know the answer, but I'm having trouble understanding, which is the entire point.

for the fill function, where fill is "fill(x, y, colorspec)"

If x and y are represented as vectors, how would I visualize them?

In the following: fill([1 -1 -1 1],[1 1 -1 -1], 'k') a black filled square is generated.

I'm just having trouble understanding how those two vectors make a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work backwards. Draw a square with corners at all possible combinations of +/-1. Label the corners with the coordinates. Trace the square from the upper right (1, 1), going counter-clockwise. You get the sequence (1, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, -1), (1, -1). The arrays `x` and `y` are the x- and y-coordinates of the points in that sequence, respectively: `x = [1, -1, -1, 1]` and `y = [1, 1, -1, -1]`.

In general, `fill` expects you to represent any n-sided polygon with two vectors of length `n` containing the x- and y-coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: Glad it helped. I remember the days when anything with graphics sucked because I was unfamiliar with things like this. It gets easier once the basics sink in.